# rails list allowed values for enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums

Given that in a model

```
enum_field :role, allowed_values: [:admin, :super_admin, :minion], default: :minion
```

Is there a built in way to access the list of allowed values without doing this:

```
def self.roles
  [:admin, :super_admin, :minion]
end
enum_field :role, allowed_values: self.roles, default: :minion
```

Answer (score 1):

oh...

```
model_name.roles
```

(I *did* try that but I did a typo)